# Detect the index of a base64 in a string

Tags: php, base64

I want to upload some files with  different extension .
Is there a way to do thing like this :

hello, "Base64 code" world!

Is there a way to detect the index of the base64 from a string to Decode it ?

the result should be : hello, "some file " world!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `base64_decode()` such as:

```
<?php

echo 'hello, "' . base64_decode("actual Base64 code") . 'Base64 code" world!';
```

The only thing you might be able to detect is if the encoding uses atypical base64 characters, but you could never know if they are mixed up.

Comment: the problem is i dont know where the base64 code is in a string

Comment: That's like providing a bunch of random characters that include the letters of your name and to find a way to extract your name.  There is no easy or even guaranteed method.